# I made an Elasticsearch Cluster, I have 3 azure VM machines, only one node is Master. The cluster keeps collapsing after some time

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, cluster-computing, docker-swarm

When you check the cluster health it will show you number of nodes are 3, then after a while it will became only one and after some time it will return back to 3.

(In addition, I also getting error on my 2nd data node "can not be imported as a dangling index, as index name already exists in cluster metadata" - not sure if this is related to the issue or a separate issue)

I'm getting below errors in my ES logs:

````
[2020-10-10T10:34:02,441][WARN ][o.e.d.z.PublishClusterStateAction] [company_master] publishing cluster state with version [99] failed for the following nodes: [[{company_node1}{ilBojvb2QNOFkCxQsz22GQ}{oXPhSf5gT6mQjMMaF2v99Q}{10.10.2.9}{10.10.2.9:9300}{ml.machine_memory=8589463552, ml.max_open_jobs=20, xpack.installed=true, ml.enabled=true}]]
[2020-10-10T10:34:02,443][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterApplierService] [company_master] removed {{company_node2}{4OoGXUfnReOuM-cQkJEhkw}{zlQ36kBfRzm7irMnUYnoOw}{10.10.2.7}{10.10.2.7:9300}{ml.machine_memory=4294496256, ml.max_open_jobs=20, xpack.installed=true, ml.enabled=true},}, reason: apply cluster state (from master [master {company_master}{kwsp-zEESeGYcdF55HGXzQ}{ZZjAUs11RwWksQCBfh8Xpw}{10.10.2.4}{10.10.2.4:9300}{ml.machine_memory=8589463552, xpack.installed=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20, ml.enabled=true} committed version [99] source [zen-disco-node-failed({company_node2}{4OoGXUfnReOuM-cQkJEhkw}{zlQ36kBfRzm7irMnUYnoOw}{10.10.2.7}{10.10.2.7:9300}{ml.machine_memory=4294496256, ml.max_open_jobs=20, xpack.installed=true, ml.enabled=true}), reason(transport disconnected)[{company_node2}{4OoGXUfnReOuM-cQkJEhkw}{zlQ36kBfRzm7irMnUYnoOw}{10.10.2.7}{10.10.2.7:9300}{ml.machine_memory=4294496256, ml.max_open_jobs=20, xpack.installed=true, ml.enabled=true} transport disconnected]]])
[2020-10-10T10:34:02,436][WARN ][o.e.g.G.InternalPrimaryShardAllocator] [company_master] [telemetry-2020.09.25][0]: failed to list shard for shard_started on node [ilBojvb2QNOFkCxQsz22GQ]
org.elasticsearch.action.FailedNodeException: Failed node [ilBojvb2QNOFkCxQsz22GQ]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.nodes.TransportNodesAction$AsyncAction.onFailure(TransportNodesAction.java:236) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.12.jar:6.8.12]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.nodes.TransportNodesAction$AsyncAction.access$200(TransportNodesAction.java:151) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.12.jar:6.8.12]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.nodes.TransportNodesAction$AsyncAction$1.handleException(TransportNodesAction.java:210) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.12.jar:6.8.12]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.sendRequest(TransportService.java:534) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.12.jar:6.8.12]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.nodes.TransportNodesAction$AsyncAction.start(TransportNodesAction.java:194) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.12.jar:6.8.12]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.nodes.TransportNodesAction.doExecute(TransportNodesAction.java:91) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.12.jar:6.8.12]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.nodes.TransportNodesAction.doExecute(TransportNodesAction.java:54) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.12.jar:6.8.12]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction$RequestFilterChain.proceed(TransportAction.java:167) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.12.jar:6.8.12]
        at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.action.filter.SecurityActionFilter.apply(SecurityActionFilter.java:121) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction$RequestFilterChain.proceed(TransportAction.java:165) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.12.jar:6.8.12]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:139) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.12.jar:6.8.12]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:81) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.12.jar:6.8.12]
        at org.elasticsearch.gateway.TransportNodesListGatewayStartedShards.list(TransportNodesListGatewayStartedShards.java:95) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.12.jar:6.8.12]
        at org.elasticsearch.gateway.AsyncShardFetch.asyncFetch(AsyncShardFetch.java:283) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.12.jar:6.8.12]
        at org.elasticsearch.gateway.AsyncShardFetch.fetchData(AsyncShardFetch.java:126) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.12.jar:6.8.12]
        at org.elasticsearch.gateway.GatewayAllocator$InternalPrimaryShardAllocator.fetchData(GatewayAllocator.java:170) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.12.jar:6.8.12]
        at org.elasticsearch.gateway.PrimaryShardAllocator.makeAllocationDecision(PrimaryShardAllocator.java:86) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.12.jar:6.8.12]
        at org.elasticsearch.gateway.BaseGatewayShardAllocator.allocateUnassigned(BaseGatewayShardAllocator.java:59) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.12.jar:6.8.12]
        at org.elasticsearch.gateway.GatewayAllocator.innerAllocatedUnassigned(GatewayAllocator.java:125) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.12.jar:6.8.12]
        at org.elasticsearch.gateway.GatewayAllocator.allocateUnassigned(GatewayAllocator.java:115) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.12.jar:6.8.12]
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.routing.allocation.AllocationService.reroute(AllocationService.java:410) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.12.jar:6.8.12]
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.routing.allocation.AllocationService.reroute(AllocationService.java:378) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.12.jar:6.8.12]
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.routing.allocation.AllocationService.reroute(AllocationService.java:361) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.12.jar:6.8.12]
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.routing.allocation.AllocationService.disassociateDeadNodes(AllocationService.java:233) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.12.jar:6.8.12]
        at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ZenDiscovery$NodeRemovalClusterStateTaskExecutor.execute(ZenDiscovery.java:636) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.12.jar:6.8.12]
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.MasterService.executeTasks(MasterService.java:643) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.12.jar:6.8.12]
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.MasterService.calculateTaskOutputs(MasterService.java:270) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.12.jar:6.8.12]
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.MasterService.runTasks(MasterService.java:200) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.12.jar:6.8.12]
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.MasterService$Batcher.run(MasterService.java:135) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.12.jar:6.8.12]
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.TaskBatcher.runIfNotProcessed(TaskBatcher.java:150) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.12.jar:6.8.12]
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.TaskBatcher$BatchedTask.run(TaskBatcher.java:188) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.12.jar:6.8.12]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:681) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.12.jar:6.8.12]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.runAndClean(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:252) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.12.jar:6.8.12]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.run(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:215) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.12.jar:6.8.12]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.transport.NodeNotConnectedException: [company_node1][10.10.2.9:9300] Node not connected
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:151) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.12.jar:6.8.12]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.getConnection(TransportService.java:576) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.12.jar:6.8.12]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.sendRequest(TransportService.java:531) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.12.jar:6.8.12]
        ... 33 more
[2020-10-10T10:34:02,462][WARN ][o.e.g.G.InternalPrimaryShardAllocator] [company_master] [telemetry-2020.09.13][0]: failed to list shard for shard_started on node [ilBojvb2QNOFkCxQsz22GQ]
org.elasticsearch.action.FailedNodeException: Failed node [ilBojvb2QNOFkCxQsz22GQ]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.nodes.TransportNodesAction$AsyncAction.onFailure(TransportNodesAction.java:236) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.12.jar:6.8.12]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.nodes.TransportNodesAction$AsyncAction.access$200(TransportNodesAction.java:151) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.12.jar:6.8.12]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.nodes.TransportNodesAction$AsyncAction$1.handleException(TransportNodesAction.java:210) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.12.jar:6.8.12]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.sendRequest(TransportService.java:534) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.12.jar:6.8.12]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.nodes.TransportNodesAction$AsyncAction.start(TransportNodesAction.java:194) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.12.jar:6.8.12]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.nodes.TransportNodesAction.doExecute(TransportNodesAction.java:91) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.12.jar:6.8.12]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.nodes.TransportNodesAction.doExecute(TransportNodesAction.java:54) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.12.jar:6.8.12]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction$RequestFilterChain.proceed(TransportAction.java:167) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.12.jar:6.8.12]
        at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.action.filter.SecurityActionFilter.apply(SecurityActionFilter.java:121) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction$RequestFilterChain.proceed(TransportAction.java:165) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.12.jar:6.8.12]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:139) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.12.jar:6.8.12]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:81) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.12.jar:6.8.12]```
````

Comment: Hi, Your must be able to connect to each VMs port 9200 and 9300 from other VM. Have you set this and checked?

Comment: Can you provide more info about elasticsearch? Which version of elastic are you running? What commands you used to start ES? If you deployed elastic using docker stack, provide the docker-compose file you used

Comment: Elasticsearch  version 6.8.12
I installed elasticsearch as a service

Below is the docker-compose file

version: "3.5"

Comment: Elasticsearch  version 6.8.12
I installed elasticsearch as a service

Below is the docker-compose file

version: "3.5"

services:

auth:
web:
api:
dashboard-proxy:
data:
telemetry-proxy:
scheduler:
redis:

networks:
    companee:
        driver: overlay
        ipam:
            driver: default
            config:
                - subnet: 10.100.0.0/24